# TYPO3 - ContentElement TextWithImage - Given sizes (height / width) are not recognized

Tags: output, typo3, typoscript

I face an issue with TYPO3 v7.6.19 that given size information (height / width) are not recognized / taken into account in frontend output.

System-information:
TYPO3 v7.6.19 with styled_content_information

Does someone know a typoscript snippet or a patch for the system or how to solve the issue?

I did a search an extended search with google but didn't find anything feasible.

Comment: 1) Can you give us an example? What dimensions did you try to write?
2) Maybe trivial question: Did you check if imagemagick/graphicsmagick is up and running?

Comment: Was there a change from Imagemagick 6 to Imagemagick 7. Syntax is different. convert goes to magick in Imagemagick 7.

Comment: No, there was only a minor change in the typo3 version, nothing more. In addition we face the issue that image previews are not shown / generated. I have two possibilities in mind: Either it is a problem with the file abstraction layer or it might be a problem with the apache server / users. What I understand from you guys is that there is no issue known with the typo3 installation itself, right? I will check the apache / user topic and let you know. But if you have proposals please let me know.

Comment: Ok, got realy strange behavior. I changed the file user to the apache-user and now it looks like that the images resizing is working. Nevertheless when I resize an image exactly to 200px the original size (>200px) will be keeped.  When I change the size either to less than 200px (199) or even higher (201) the resizing is working and the image will be shown resized in the frontend. Strange! Looks like that 200px is some hard border but in the end it is not understandable.

Answer (score 0):

yes, ImageMagick is up and running. All tests in the install tool are successfully. All example pictures are shown properly.

The element was already there (given by some admin) and it is a normal content element (TextWithImage). It is set that the width of the image should has a size of 200px but the image is not decreased to this size.

It was working before but since we did a minor upgrade vom Version 7.6.16 to 7.6.19 it is not anymore working.

Best regards

Udo